ASGI for django not compatible with Server-sent-events?
I previously wrote an SSE (Server sent event) request using Django and it looked all right.
    def event_stream():
        """
        Generator function to yield messages.
        """
        for i in range(10):
            yield f"data: Message {i}\n\n"
            time.sleep(1)  # Simulate delay in message generation
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    response['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'
    return response

Later, I installed channels because I needed to use websocket, and switched from WSGI to using ASGI.
At this point, I noticed that the request was not returning properly, but was returning all the data at once at the end. I'm not sure what is causing this or how to fix it.
I'm sure my code hasn't changed and it's only the difference between wsgi and asgi that's causing the problem.
python version:3.11.7
django version:5.0.6
channels version:3.0.5

StreamingHttpResponse was never the way to go from the very beginning. When you choose to use Daphne over the WSGI server that Django is built with, you are essentially saying: "I want to go asynchronous however I can". This means that synchronous views which behaved like coroutines even though they weren’t, will no longer behave normally.
